# Thousand Cuts area seen from atop The Bunker - how to get to it?

Tags: borderlands-2

I just defeated The Bunker during the mission *Where Angels Fear to Tread*, and was taking in the view when I noticed one of those incandescent-bulb directional arrows off in the distance.

It is high atop a mountain and points down to a plateau beneath it, and just below that plateau is a lake, where if you watch long enough you'll see a thresher spawn.

So I'm wondering if that's an Easter Egg of some sort, or is it truly an area you can reach?

[image: Thousand Cuts Mystery Area]

I'm playing on the PS3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your a viewing [Terramorphous the Invincible (small spoiler)](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Terramorphous_the_Invincible). It's a mission ([You. Will. Die. (Seriously)](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/You._Will._Die._(Seriously.))) that you will recieve way later in the game and the area is accessible only via thousand cuts.

Comment: You. Will. Die. (Seriously) is not an understatement. You will seriously die a lot.